# WPF The type or namespace name 'Browser' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, namespaces

I currently changing my application from Silverlight to WPF. I have this peice of code which is giving me an error in wpf.

The error which i get is:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Browser' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\sahluwai\Desktop\cusControls2\leitch\HarrisSilverlightToolkit\Toolkit\Source\Core\BaseComponents\HelpManager.cs    148 52  BaseComponents

```
private void OpenHelpFileForThisControl(Control passedControl)
    {
        if (passedControl != null)
        {
 //////////////////This line gives an error as System.windows.Brower is not present in wpf

            string uriCurrent = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.OriginalString;
            if ((uriCurrent.LastIndexOf('/') + 1) < uriCurrent.Length)
            {
                uriCurrent = uriCurrent.Remove(uriCurrent.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            }

            System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(uriCurrent + HTMLPrefix + ((string)passedControl.Tag)), "_blank");
        }
    }
```

So the the question now is what should i replace it now with so that this works in wpf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WPF you should use a System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser instead of a Browser

Comment: visual studio intellisense does not show me "Navigate"  method  and neither does it have "HtmlPage" for System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser .Any idea about that.

Comment: Look at the documentation. Conversions are never going to be exactly the same. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx You can change the Source to get to a new page.